# Infinite loop during CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

I am using the *CGAL* library for triangulating a 3D point-cloud. Some times the application works fine, but most of the time it gets stuck. It enters an infinite loop while inserting a new 3D point in the triangulation. This problem I get only on Windows, on Linux it works fine always. I am using CGAL 4.6 x64 with the kernel *Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel* with Visual Studio 2012/2015 on Windows 8.1 x64, and GCC on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem on the Windows build?

UPDATE: Follow this link to find the minimal code to reproduce the problem and a sample data-set: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8bb0qT4PvT8V2hqUEt0RUstLTg
The problem seems to be in the optimized procedure of searching the nearest point and inserting a new point (the two pieces of code decided before compilation are equivalent, but the second is optimized in two ways: use only one *locate()* instead of two and do not allocate/use a *std::vector* for each point).

Comment: please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please find the mcve on the updated question

Comment: What compiler options are you using? CGAL relies on precise rounding of double operations.

Comment: all compile flags are in the CMakeList.txt distributed along with the code; in order to be compatible with CGAL on linux I am forced to use -frounding-math

Comment: On Windows, you must use the compiler flag `/fp:strict` and you can add `/fp:except-` to loosen the "strictness" a bit.
Edit: I saw your `CMakeLists.txt` and I am pretty sure it can be the reason of the failure. I should probably promote this comment to an official answer.

Comment: @Irineau: Thank you for your suggestion, however, even if not appearing in the CMakeList.txt, I have already tried with and without setting those flags on Windows, and it makes no difference. So if this flags are a problem, they are only a part of the problem, there must be something else also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bug is in your `struct adjacent_vertex_back_inserter_t`
The `operator=` should be as follows:

```
    inline void operator=(const vertex_handle_t& w) {
      assert(! delaunay.is_infinite(v))
        if ( !delaunay.is_infinite(w) && (delaunay.geom_traits().compare_distance_3_object()(p, w->point(), v->point()) == CGAL::SMALLER)){
          v = w;
      }
```

Comment: Indeed, I tested and this solves the problem on Windows; thank you. Still I find it a bit odd that on Linux the problem doesn't manifest and the output is as expected. This is why I didn't triple check the code, I was sure it was only something platform related.